# Counting calculation operations and writing them into a file from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

guys. I'm new to Linux and shell scripting in general and I have a question.

I have the following simple calculator:

```
input="yes"
while [[ $input = "yes" ]]
do

    PS3="Press 1 for Addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication and 4 for division: "
    select math in Addition Subtraction Multiplication Division
    do
        case "$math" in
        Addition)
            echo "Enter first no:"
            read num1
            echo "Enter second no:"
            read num2
            result=`expr $num1 + $num2`
            COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
            echo Answer: $result
            break
        ;;
        Subtraction)
            echo "Enter first no:"
            read num1
            echo "Enter second no:"
            read num2
            result=`expr $num1 - $num2`
            echo Answer: $result
            break
        ;;
        Multiplication)
            echo "Enter first no:"
            read num1
            echo "Enter second no:"
            read num2
            result=`expr $num1 * $num2`
            echo Answer: $result
            break
        ;;
        Division)
            echo "Enter first no:"
            read num1
            echo "Enter second no:"
            read num2
            result=$(expr "scale=2; $num1/$num2" | bc)
            echo Answer = $result
            break
        ;;
        *)
            echo Choose 1 to 4 only!!!!
            break
        ;;
    esac
    done

done
```

All I want is to be able to count the operations (meaning that for a successfull operation is +1, like "2 + 5 = 7" and some counter variable goes +1.. then something else and again +1) untill the user types something to stop the calculator. Then the counter variable (which holds the total number of operations performed) should be written inside a new file. How can I do this or can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter:

- set `count=0` before the loop
- increment the counter after successful operation with `((count++))` after checking the status (`$?`) of the arithmetic operation
- write the count to a file with `printf "%d\n" "$count" > file`

Not sure why you want to write to a new file each time. If that is the desired behavior, you can generate a new filename each time.  Probably, you could name your file as `operation.txt.N` where N is the counter.

You can add `Quit` as an option that user can select:

```
PS3="Press 1 for Addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, 4 for division and 5 to Quit: "
select math in Addition Subtraction Multiplication Division Quit
... existing code here ...
```

And add this case:

```
    Quit)
        input=no
        break
    ;;
```

Comment: So when I get out of the While loop I need to write `printf "%d\n" "$count" > file` ? Can you give me an example how to get out of the while loop?

Comment: You already have the logic to break out of the loop when the user chooses an option other than 1 through 4.  You can put the printf after the loop if that is what you want.

Comment: No, when the user enters something other than 1-4 it asks him to enter again.  :)